# Can IBDesignable and IBInspectable run on iOS7 phone?

Tags: swift, ios7, ibdesignable, ibinspectable

I'm using Xcode7.1, and used `@IBDesignable` and `@IBInspectable` to custom a view. When I set the `Deployment Target` to `iOS7.0`, the property I set with `IBInspectable` didn't work. Does it work on iPhone with `iOS7.0`?